# How do metric tensors behave in complex vector spaces?

Tags: complex-analysis, tensors

I'm having trouble understanding how metric tensors work over complex vector spaces. I have two main questions:

1. Are complex metrics symmetric or skew-symmetric? Why?
2. How are magnitudes enforced to be real? For example, let's find the magnitude of $\vec v = \langle1+i, 1+i\rangle$ with the metric $g=\delta$. If I calculate $v^ig_{ij}v^j$ I get $4i$, which is clearly not real, and neither is its square root $\sqrt{4i}=||v||$. How does this make sense? Shouldn't magnitudes be real (and positive)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll reserve $i$ for a square root of $-1$. The choice $g_{ab}=\delta_{ab}$ is familiar in real spaces with inner product $u^a\delta_{ab}v^b$. The complex counterpart $\bar{u}^a\delta_{ab}v^b$ (or $u^a\delta_{ab}\bar{v}^b$; it's a matter of convention) leaves the metric tensor unchanged. This is what happens in general, so we want $\bar{u}^ag_{ab}v^b$.

Comment: Oh, thank you! That explains a lot, I didn't think that it'd just be changing the definition of the dot product with the metric :)

Answer (score 0):

The standard definition of an [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) on a complex vector space makes it neither symmetric nor skew-symmetric; instead it is *conjugate-symmetric* or *Hermitian* which means it satisfies

$$\langle x, y \rangle = \overline{ \langle y, x \rangle }.$$

This forces $\langle x, x \rangle$ to be real and then we further require in the definition that $\langle x, x \rangle \ge 0$ with equality iff $x = 0$ (positive-definiteness). The standard inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$ is

$$\langle (x_1, \dots x_n), (y_1, \dots y_n) \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \overline{x_i} y_i$$

(note the complex conjugates in the first variable). Among other things, this definition has the pleasant property that it reduces to the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ if we expand each coordinate out into real and imaginary parts.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I already understand how dot products work in general; I was trying to figure out how it relates to complex tensors :)

Comment: @Erez: complex inner products aren't tensors! But perhaps I never understood your question since I don't understand how the other answer answers it.